# Should I use homebrew or the official downloader to install nodejs?

Tags: macbook-pro, homebrew

I recently bought a mac, and I need to know what the difference between installing nodejs (or any application for that matter) through homebrew and official downloader is? What's the recommended method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with .pkg installer downloaded from official website. Seems to be the same with brew. Don't forget to update Homebrew.

Answer (score -1):

I'm daily programing in node.js and I recommend to install nvm, either you use it via Terminal, iTerm or via Homebrew.

For brew, you can use this:

```
brew install nvm
```

For another method, you can use wget:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Both of them can be found [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nvm)
or [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)